# htaccess rewrite - file name not recognized

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, url-rewriting, php-7

Been working on this for days, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have two files in a dir:

1. index.php - which loads a list of articles in a news section
2. article.php - which loads the article file itself with contents

Below, I get stuck on the first rule on the index.php file in the .htaccess file. (Tried many things, the includes and files are all OK, but the htaccess rules I have here don't get passed the index.php. The article file loads fine as well. Except when applying these two lines below.)

the link:

```
domain.com/news/index/66/bass (works)
```

Defined by:

```
RewriteRule ^/?news/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /news/index.php?news_id=$1&page_id=$1 [QSA,NC]
```

Next, on that page we click to:

```
domain.com/news/article/66-17506/SEO-FRIENDLY-TITLE
```

Defined by:

```
RewriteRule ^/?news/[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /news/article.php?news_id=$1&page_id=$1 [QSA,NC]
```

And there I get stuck on the previous definition of index.php.
I already deleted the [L] value and tried many things. I guess all that's needed is the **article.php** to be loaded.

Any help would save a lot of articles online!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that both your regexes for matching the URL are the same. So anything that might match the article.php rule will already have been grabbed by the index.php rule. Can you perhaps change the two rules to this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?news/index/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /news/index.php?news_id=$1&page_id=$1 [QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?news/article/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /news/article.php?news_id=$1&page_id=$1 [QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I had to set the first rule with 'index' (and another one above it) - and leave out the 'article' in the two rules below it to fix this. This one really saved the day for me. Thanks again!